# How do i make my Pods in Kubernetes Cluster (GKE) to use the Node's IP Address to communicate to the VMs outside the cluster

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, firewall, vpn

I have created a Kubernetes Cluster on Google Cloud using GKE service.

The GCP Environment has a VPC which is connected to the on-premises network using a VPN. The GKE Cluster is created in a subnet, say subnet1, in the same VPC. The VMs in the subnet1 are able to communicate to an on-premises endpoint on its internal(private) ip address. The complete subnet's ip address range(10.189.10.128/26) is whitelisted in the on-premises firewall.

The GKE Pods use the ip addresses out of the secondary ip address assigned to them(10.189.32.0/21). I did exec in one of the pods and tried to hit the on-premise network but was not able to get a response. When i checked the network logs, i found that the source ip was Pod's IP(10.189.37.18) which was used to communicate with the on-premises endpoint(10.204.180.164). Where as I want that the Pod should use the Node's IP Address to communicate to the on-premises endpoint.

There is a deployment done for the Pods and the deployment is exposed as a ClusterIP Service. This Service is attached to a GKE Ingress.

Comment: Running into the same configuration, would be interested in a solution, if any was found :)

Comment: Configured an NGINX reverse proxy in the same private subnet as the GKE nodes and created a host entry in each pod to point to this NGINX proxy's IP for hitting the on-premises endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I found IP masquerade is applied on GKE cluster, so when your pods are talking together, they are seeing their real IP but if one pod is talking to a resource on internet, the node IP is used instead.

The default configuration for this rule on GKE is : 10.0.0.0/8
So any IP in the range is considered as internal and will use the pods' IP to communicate.

Hopefully, this range can be easily changed :

- you have to enable **Network policy** on your cluster, this can be done through GKE UI in GCP console, this will enable [calico](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/network-policy-provider/) networking on your cluster
- you create a configmap that will be used by calico to exclude some IP ranges from this behavior :

`apiVersion: v1
data:
  config: |
    nonMasqueradeCIDRs:
      - 10.149.80.0/21   <-- this IP range will now be considered as external and use nodes' IP
    resyncInterval: 60s
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ip-masq-agent
  namespace: kube-system`

Comment: I referred the doc and looks like what all IP we add in `nonMasqueradeCIDRs`, When packets are sent to these destinations, your cluster does not masquerade IP address sources and preserves source Pod IP addresses IP .
What you are mentioning is opposite of what mentioned in the doc 

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent#console_1